# Send push notification to a specific test device using OneSignal push notification service

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I added push notification support to my iOS app using OneSignal some time before. The app is made in Xcode with Swift.

I want to send a test push notification only to my test device(s). I the documentation I found the following manual: [How do I send a notification to a single user?](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/user-user-messages)

I managed to create the segment but I don't know where to put this peace of code: `OneSignal.sendTag("is_test", "true")`

Does anybody know where I have to put this piece of code to make it working as I described above?

I uploaded my code here: https://codeshare.io/DxcNn

Thanks,
David.

**Update:**

OneSignal now also supports to set a device as test device without doing something in the code. You can also download your own app from App Store and use it as test device. Just select you device from devices list one OneSignal and mark it as test device. You can find your device in the list by model, version and/or time added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sendTag method is from the device sdk. In your case iOS.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--sendtag-

You should do this anytime after initWithLaunchOptions in the app delegate. Updated code based on comments

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let oneSignal = OneSignal(launchOptions: launchOptions, appId: "here_is_my_onesignal_app_id") { (message, additionalData, isActive) in
            NSLog("OneSignal Notification opened:\nMessage: %@", message)

            if additionalData != nil {
                NSLog("additionalData: %@", additionalData)
                // Check for and read any custom values you added to the notification
                // This done with the "Additonal Data" section the dashbaord.
                // OR setting the 'data' field on our REST API.
                if let customKey = additionalData["customKey"] as! String? {
                    NSLog("customKey: %@", customKey)
                }
            }


        }
        OneSignal.defaultClient().sendTag("is_test", value: "true")

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

Comment: `sendTag` and `sendTags` can be called anytime after `initWithLaunchOptions`. It doesn't have to be called after `registerForPushNotifications` even if `autoRegister` is set to false.

Comment: Still didn't get it work. I'm using this code: [CodeShare.io](https://codeshare.io/DxcNn). Where do I have to add this piece of code? Code: `OneSignal.sendTag("is_test", "true")`

Comment: Just edited with the code. Please note that you need to use the instance call oneSignal and not the class OneSignal

Comment: The solution was to add the following outside the oneSignal code: `OneSignal.defaultClient().sendTag("test", value: "true")`